# I got an error running undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv4kB.png)

Comment: Please edit your post so that your question does not contain [images of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add "use_subprocess=True" to closure like this:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).